# Can Regular Expression Match Texts Incrementally?

Tags: .net, xml, regex

I am using regex to capture strings from xml. The input text is split to the innerText of nodes. When regex match something, I want to know its xpath as well. For example,

```
       <root>
         <node>aabb</node>
         <node>bcccd</node>
       </root>
```

I want to capture "([a-zA-Z])\1{2}" and it comes out 2 results--((bb,/*[1]/*[1]) (b,/*[1]/*[2])) and (ccc,/*[1]/*[2]).

Now I am trying to find a way to run a regular expression incrementally. Does anybody know how to achieve it or if there are some workarounds or good ideas.

Comment: why 2 results...with `([a-zA-Z])\1{2}` it would match only `ccc`

Comment: I mean I want skip the <node> ,just like Match("aabbbccd");but in fact I can't concat the innerText(I know how but it's not allowed),so I was looking for ideas...

Comment: you can do it..check out my ans

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex to parse xml..Use linq2xml..

You can use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx).

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXml.xml");
var lst=doc.Elements("node")
           .Select(x=>x.Value);
string text= string.Join("",lst);
```

And the result would be

```
aabbbcccd
```

Comment: Actually It's not a parse problem, I have several types to deal with,and only xml has this problem. In the example, I want to capture 3 same letters using "([a-zA-Z])\1{2}", "bbb" is split to "bb" and "b", I want to capture it ,too.

Comment: I know I can get the "bbb" by string.join, but I can't get the xpath.Do you have any idea?